# Need help using xAPI [XTB Broker] - python wrapper API connector - problems with additional parameters of commands

Tags: python

I need some help with python `xAPIConnector.py`.
Link: https://xopenhub.pro/api/wrappers/

For now I can log in, log out and use command `getAllSymbols` which does not require any additional parameters.
Now the problem arises with commands that require additiona parameters.

(I have tried both commands that I'm listing below):

1. Command `getChartLastRequest` which require additional parameters:
   (Here I've got problems with "code sample" button for some reason, so forgive that the code is not framed.

   {

   ```
       "period": 5, # minutes : int
       "start": 1661212800000, # unix time & date : int
       "symbol": "PKN.PL" # symbol : str
   ```

   }

Documentation link: http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/#getChartLastRequest

2. Command `getSymbol` also require additional parameters:

   {"command": "getSymbol", "arguments": {"symbol": "EURPLN"}}

Documentation link: http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/#getSymbol

For the first command I have wrote a simple function:

```
def getChartLastRequest(self, symbol_name : str, period : int, time : int):

    parameters = {
        "period": period,
        "start": time,
        "symbol": symbol_name
    }

    price_init = self.client.commandExecute(commandName='getChartLastRequest', arguments=parameters)

    return price_init
```

But I got the following error:
[image]

For the second command when I tried to run it like this:

```
resp = self.client.commandExecute(commandName='getSymbol', arguments='EURUSD')
```

I got the following error:
[image]

Perhaps I do not understand something but can someone help me with getting this to work?
I have no clue if I am giving wrongly formatted parameters or if I am doing something else wrong.
I tried what I could but I can't figure these things out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems, I have figured it out.
the `attributes` parameter of `APIClient.commandExecute()` should receive a `dictionary` object or nested `dictionary`.
In documentation for `getChartLastRequest` command there is `{"info" : {dict}}` line in showed example:

```
{
    "command": "getChartLastRequest",
    "arguments": {
        "info": CHART_LAST_INFO_RECORD
    }
}
```

So If I want to get prices from the last month I pass the values to the `attributes` in the following manner:

```
params = {"info" : {
       "period" : period,
       "start" : time_date_unix,
       "symbol" : symbol_name
}}
```

And initialise it as follows:

`APIClient.commandExecute(commandName='getChartLastRequest', attributes=params)`

For the `getSymbol` command you need to pass the attributes in the following manner:

```
params = {
       "symbol" : symbol_name
}
```

To anyone who had the similar problem. Just be cautious when reading the documentation and think calmly, otherwise you will loose a lot of nerves and time like me...

Always pass a `dictionary` object or nested `dictionary`.